# Know If user has redeemed an offer code in iOS using RevenueCat api?

Tags: ios, revenuecat

I'm planning to integrate Subscription Offer Codes. If we use standard validation receipt method, then it returns offer_code_ref_name key, But I want to know if RevenueCat provides similar key in its PurchaserInfo Object. If not then is there any other way to know if code is redeemed, using RevenueCat api?